# mySQL Administrator can't connect to database server cause Error Host now allowed

Tags: mysql, centos

it return error can't connect to 192.168.1.100 (ip of server)
Error Host 192.169.1.9 is now allowed

how to fixed this ?

system running on VM CentOS 6, when use phpmyadmin are work well but not work with MySQL GUI Administrator Tool

here is my iptables

```
# Firewall configuration written by system-config-firewall
# Manual customization of this file is not recommended.
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
-A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 10000 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 10082 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
COMMIT
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have your MySQL server listening on all interfaces/public interface then the problem is likely with your user table. There is a 'host' value that defines which hosts are permitted to access the MySQL server (which you can change from the phpMyAdmin Privileges tab). Your host value doesn't match the one you are trying to connect from (i.e. the host value might be 'localhost', a common value, and you are not connecting from 'localhost'). I believe it is also possible to setup a separate Hosts table for more complex permissions.

See: http://www.howtoforge.com/forums/showthread.php?t=12455